# Conditional Compliation Constant VB

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors, compilation, conditional-compilation

```
Error   BC31030 Conditional compilation constant '; ^^ ^^ EXCLUDE_CODEGEN' is not valid: Identifier expected.   GpsHost C:\Projects\GpsTrackSolution\GpsHost\vbc    1   N/A
```

I am getting the above error when I try and build a VB.NET win forms app. I refactored it a little, updated to framework 4.7.2 and now I am getting this.

There is NO reference in ANY vbproj for that string of characters, either partial or full. I've done a find in file contents across the entire solution and cannot find that anywhere. Almost at my wit's end as to what could be doing this.

Comment: It appears to be a constant set in the command-line (`vbc`), which overrides what's in the Project designer (if something is set there). [Conditional Compilation in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/conditional-compilation)

Comment: Somehow your vbproj file acquired the following: `<DefineConstants>;</DefineConstants>` in the `<PropertyGroup>` for the build configuration. Note the single **;**. The **^^** characters are likely some internal message formatting placeholders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was unrelated to VB, it was actually due to Orleans code generation trying to insert constants. Orleans isn't really designed to work with VB, so I switched to runtime codegen, instead of build time, and it worked.