# Invalid conditional compilation constant

Tags: .net, vb.net, orleans

Trying to follow this Orleans [tutorial](https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/tutorials_and_samples/tutorial_1.html) in vb.net (not C# as in the tutorial), I have the following error in two projects in the solution:

```
1>vbc : error BC31030: Conditional compilation constant '; ^^ ^^ EXCLUDE_CODEGEN' is not valid: Identifier expected.
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55006418/conditional-compliation-constant-vb) it is just a matter of "*switching to runtime codegen instead of buildtime*". I do not know how to do this, that's my question.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable run-time code generation by installing the `Microsoft.Orleans.OrleansCodeGenerator` package into your client and silo projects and configuring the client and silo to generate code for your assemblies using this code:

```cs
builder.ConfigureApplicationParts(
    parts => parts
        .AddApplicationPart(typeof(MyGrainType).Assembly)
        .WithCodeGeneration());
```

There is documentation on this here: https://dotnet.github.io/orleans/Documentation/grains/code_generation.html#during-initialization